# Mongoose restructure query to match result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that would run the following:

```
      var RandomNumber = rand(Start,End); // 186


..findOne({start: {"$gte": RandomNumber }, end: {"$lte": RandomNumber }}).then(function (winner) {
```

in my database i have the following input:

```
_id:5c8d037c5a35fd36e4b27e10
userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
start:169
end:268
time:1552745340629
```

How do i restructure my query so it would return the input database? as 186 is within start and end values.

EDIT: have also tried without quotes in the query. Im not in particular sure how i would make the query match if start or end is correct value, or if the value is somewhere between those two.

edit two:

i also have

```
      var RandomNumber = rand(Start,End); // equals 186. that i need to get the winning row.
```

**EDit three:**

How can i edit:

```
..findOne({start: {"$gte": RandomNumber }, end: {"$lte": RandomNumber }}).then(function (winner) {
```

where the RandomNumber equals 186, to only give me the record in database where
the value of 186 exists? ( means between start and end value).

here are some more examples in my db:

```
_id:5c8d037c5a35fd36e4b27e10
userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
start:1
end:50
time:1552745340629

_id:5c8d037c5a35fd36e4b27e10
userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
start:51
end:168
time:1552745340629

_id:5c8d037c5a35fd36e4b27e10
userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
start:169
end:268
time:1552745340629
```

Desired output:

```
 _id:5c8d037c5a35fd36e4b27e10
    userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
    start:169
    end:268
    time:1552745340629
```

Comment: Have you tried without quotes? `{start: {$gte: 186}, end: {$lte: 186}}`

Comment: yes @AnuragSrivastava. have tried

Comment: "Number between two fields" is actually an interview question I use. You want "start to be less than" and "end to be greater than". Therefore basically the "inverse" of a between for a single field.

Comment: How would i accomplish this @NeilLunn ? cause i only know that its equal to start, or equal to end, or in between of them.

Comment: Look at the linked questions and answers and also think about what is logical. `{ start: { $lte: 186 }, end: { $gte: 186 } }` and simply compare that logic and see how it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, you are looking for a document with start value greater than 186 and less than 186

Please try this query:-

```
.findOne({start: {"$gte": 169}, end: {"$lte": 268}}).then(function (winner) {
```

or

```
 .findOne({end: {"$lte": 186}}).then(function (winner) {
```

Comment: but i only know that my winning row has ticket number 186, then i only have 186 to go from, while 186 could be the start or end value, but also in between start and end.

Comment: Did you run the above query

Comment: yeah, but i dont have any other numbers to go from other than 186 in theory.

Comment: So you won't get the above document. Its not within the range.

Comment: 186 is within start value of 169 and end value 268

Comment: No you got it wrong. What the query you are running means find a document whose start value is greater than 186 and less than 186. Now 169 is not greater than 186 so it doesn't satisfy the condition

Comment: yeah, iknow what my query is doing, but i need to change it so it would get the disired output.

Comment: The query I have given will result in the output you want

Comment: updated thread . it would return the record, but it would also return the records lower than that too.

Comment: If you want, a specific result you'll have to include a unique identifier like an id